# How do I install Keras on arm64, Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python-2.7, keras, ubuntu-16.04, arm64, tegra

I tried `pip install --user keras==1.0.6` but it fails to build scipy. It returns:

`numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found`

and

`failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-XjG1HN/scipy/`.

I also tried installing scipy alone, using [these instructions](http://www.scipy.org/install.html#installing-via-pip):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/your_user/.local/bin"
pip install --user scipy
```

But received the same errors.

Note: While posting this I realized I didn't replace `your_user` with `$USER`. However, I found a different solution, see answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

This successfully installed scipy on an arm64 Ubuntu 16.04 (on NVIDIA's Jetson TX1 with Jetpack 2.3).

The additional packages include lapack and blas packages, which the error alluded to.

> The following additional packages will be installed:
>     lib**blas**-common lib**blas**3 libgfortran3 lib**lapack**3 python-decorator python-imaging python-numpy
>     python-pil

And then to install keras 1.0.6:

`pip install --user keras==1.0.6`

---

I found this answer by googling "install scipy "arm64"" and finding [Xenial (16.04) : python-scipy package : Ubuntu - Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/python-scipy).